# CSS divs: display:table alternative?

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="wr">
    <div id="con">
        <div id="unknownWidth">some box with unknown width</div>
    </div>
    <div id="knownWidth"></div>
</div>

#wr {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:50px;
}
#knownWidth {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px auto;    
    border:1px solid gray;
}
#unknownWidth{
    height:30px;
    margin:0px auto;    
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is link to fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7EsMR/

Is it possible to avoid using `display:table` on `#unknownWidth` box and keep the same functionality as it offers?

Need it to work in IE7, but not IE6. :D

Required result:
http://jsfiddle.net/7EsMR/1/

Thanks ;)

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `display: inline` on the child and `text-align: center` on the wrap:

http://jsfiddle.net/3snzb/2/

Comment: i'm afraid OP needs IE7 support :-/

Comment: @ptriek Ah right, updated to `display: inline`, which I just checked. He'll just have to do some fiddling with the heights.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `display:inline` + `text-align:center` might do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/kG846/2/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do:

```
#wr {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:50px;
    text-align: center; 
}
#knownWidth {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px auto;    
    border:1px solid gray;
}
#unknownWidth{
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Should work in IE7 since inline-block is supported.