# IE9 Bug? display: table, width: calc()

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

i'm quite perplexed by a IE9 specific issue I have at the moment, wondering if i'm doing anything wrong or whether anyone has encountered this before.

It seems if I use calc() + display: table; on an element IE9 can't handle it?

I've put it in a JS Bin here: http://jsbin.com/himuhume/1/

Or, reproduction steps are:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <span>Calc without display works</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inside break">
    </div>
    <span>Calc display table does not</span>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: grey;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 50px;
}

.inside {
  width: calc(90% + 10px);
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.break {
    display: table;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, cheers :)

Comment: It looks like calc() only has partial support in IE9.  That might have something to do with it.  http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: I can't seem to find anything detailing what "partial" support means, looking through the docs the only thing i've found is surrounding the whitespace needed surrounding the operand

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what partial support means either.  You might of discovered a random bug.  After a quick Google search for display table alternative, I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605276/css-divs-displaytable-alternative

Comment: Unfortunately I need display: table-cell support, may have to throw another node in there to do the calc and have the table display 100% of the calc'd container.

Thanks for trying to help though, really appreciate it :)

Comment: To see the _Partial Support_ explanation click on the _Known Issues_ tab. I cannot see anything in the _Known Issues_ that might be the cause of your problem though!

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that the bug exists, IE9 doesn't apply calc() width on DIVs with display:table. 
Possible workarounds are:

1. adding a node outside the display:table DIV, applying the calc() width to it and applying 100% width to the display:table DIV.
2. floating the contents instead of using display:table