# Center aligning pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm doing pagination with will_paginate and used the code to style my pagination links based off the style Digg uses.  Here's the [link to the "guide"](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/will_paginate/).  I'm trying to center align the pagination but can't seem to get the actual links to center.  I've tried wrapping them in their own div and doing the margin: auto; but the links still stay left aligned.  Thanks in advance, here's the rails and css code:

Rails

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="page_info">
        <%= page_entries_info @vars %>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination_links">
        <%= will_paginate @vars, param_name: 'index_paginate', :container => false %>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pagination {
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
  /* self-clearing method: */ }
  .pagination a, .pagination span, .pagination em {
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px; }
  .pagination .disabled {
    color: #999999;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd; }
  .pagination .current {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #2e6ab1;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #2e6ab1; }
  .pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #105cb6;
    border: 1px solid #9aafe5; }
  .pagination a:hover, .pagination a:focus {
    background: white;
    color: #000044;
    border-color: #000044; }
.pagination .pagination_links {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}
  .pagination .page_info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #2e6ab1;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    width: 22em;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em; }
  .pagination .page_info b {
    color: #000033;
    background: #6aa6ed;
    padding: 0.1em 0.25em; }
  .pagination:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden; }
  * html .pagination {
    height: 1%; }
  *:first-child + html .pagination {
    overflow: hidden; }
```

UPDATE: I'm new to CSS and thought the div autosized itself to its contents.  I was looking for a solution that did just this as an answer.  After I realized what I was looking for I googled it and found the answer.

Comment: i don't see <table class="center"> in your markup...did u mean to include that in the css?

Comment: yes i shouldn't have included that first part as it's irrelevant to the question sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/B2Ku3/ for you to see the answer. It requires you wrap the div with class of pagination in a wrapping div and then give that a width with

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply trick, this doesn't work however because this centers the whole pagination in the page.  I want the links to be centered as well.  You can see this in your fiddle by removing all the pages but 1, 2, and 3 and changing the background color inside .pagination to black.

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work with pagination which has dynamically size.

Comment: I tried this on will_paginate using the renderer: FoundationPagination::Rails and it worked exactly as I'd like - the links are now centered. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
 and make width 50% in digg_pagination class

 <div class="pagination">
    <div class="page_info" style="text-align: right">
         <%= page_entries_info @vars %>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination_links">
         <%= will_paginate @vars, param_name: 'index_paginate', :container => false %>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: see my comment on tricks answer, it applies here as well if I understand you correctly thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your centered to have a width, I would suggest checking [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353345/3843101).