# How do I center align the items in my menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, nav

How do I center align the items WITHIN in my menu? (The `li`s) I managed to center the menu (`ul`) within the page of my website but I can't center the actual items in the menu (Home, About, etc.)

You can edit my HTML/CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/66reH/ 
To see the results

**CSS/HTML:**

```css
#nav {
 font-family: Century Gothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 background-color: #eee;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 38px;
 width: 913px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:4px;
 border-color: #000;
}
#nav ul {
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 170px;
}
#nav ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px;
}
#nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #CD0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" align="center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TOUR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PHILANTHROPY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- remove the align property on the `#nav` div
- Add `text-align: center;` to the `#nav` selector CSS
- remove the `margin-left` property for the `ul` selector CSS
- add '`text-align: center;` to the `ul` selector CSS
- remove the `float: left;` property on the `li` selector CSS
- add `display: inline-block;` to the `li` selector CSS

You didn't have a centered menu there. You simply added 170px to the left of the UL in the CSS so it sort of *looked* centered. But it wasn't.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/66reH/1/)

Comment: Looks pretty centered. Seems to be about 5px too far to the right though. That may be due to padding on the li items or some other css.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

CSS/HTML

```css
#nav {
    font-family: Century Gothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 38px;
    width: 913px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:4px;
    border-color: #000;
}
#nav ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #CD0000;
}
.outer {
    float: right;
    right: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    float: right;
    right: -50%;
    position: relative;
}
.clearboth {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav" align="center">
         
  <div class="outer">
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TOUR</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PRESS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PHILANTHROPY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZpfj/22/)

Read more on centering:

[Centering a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width)