# <p> element inheriting width from a centered <img> above it

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I have an image that can be a variable width (min:`100px`, max:`100%` [760px]). I also have a `<p>` element that is to be shown right below the image. I'd like the `<p>` to end up with the same width as the `<img>`, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Here is the code involved in such a scenario [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9rEh/):

**html**:

```
<div id='page'>
    <figure>
        <img src='http://www.myimage.com/img.jpg'/>
        <p>Hi there. I am some text. I would like to start where the image starts :(</p>
    </figure>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
#page {
    width:760px; /* arbitrary */
}

figure img {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

figure p {
    /* ??? */
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you like this http://jsfiddle.net/a9rEh/1/??

Comment: You're going to need to define a width for the `figure` that's the width of the image.

Comment: @davidpauljunior What if I don't know the width of the image? Are you saying I'd have to use javascript to read the image size and then alter the css based on that?

Comment: @Beginner Unfortunately, no. As I mentioned, the text is to be shown directly below the image.

Comment: What is your purpose of doing that? Do you want to make a caption?

Comment: Best practice for this you have to use table to place image and captio.

Comment: @PandiyanCool you mean `display: table`, using a <table> is not best practice as this isn't tabular data.

Comment: @asubanovsky If you swap `p` to `figcaption`, the layout doesn't change.

Comment: @davidpauljunior i tried to said what u r answered

Comment: Found an interesting question/answer on here that might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width?rq=1

Comment: Here is one solution I found: http://jsfiddle.net/a9rEh/9/ You may also want to look at the caption property.

Comment: @AidanMueller The widths are not the same in that fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: table` on the `figure` and set a small width on it.  Because it's a table layout it'll then become as wide as the content, in this case the image.

```
figure {
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9rEh/6/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, the image is no longer centered within its parent element.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting solution. Would you say that a solution of that type would be following "best practices"?

Comment: @a.real.human.being Well it's the only way I know that uses CSS only, and semantically it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is inheriting from `#page` div. not from the image. Please see the same fiddle updated. 
But, You can control individual elements. You have to specify how you wish it to look like.

Comment: I think the OP means that they want the `<p>` to inherit the width from the image, not that it already is.

Comment: Oh k, In which case he has to know the width of the image in advance. Dynamically setting values in css ?? inheriting rules from siblings ? I dont think it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/asubanovsky/Y55XD/) that I made using

HTML:

```
<div id='page'>
    <figure>
        <img src='http://www.iiacanadanationalconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/test.jpg'/>
        <figcaption>Hi there. I am some text. I would like to start where the image starts :(</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#page {
    width:760px; /* arbitrary */
}


figure{
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Actually there are several ways to make an image caption, such as using `<table>`. I'm not saying that this is the best way to do that. But this is the easiest way since I see you're using `<figure>` there. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have reduced the image size and updated the fiddle. Please see that it is breaking this use case