# issue in Centering a div block without the width , last div with wrong position

Tags: html, css, width

I refered [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width) Question ,as per guidelines I made "ul" => align-center , "li" => display:inline-block; But i dont understand how , its giving problem on last Arrow in ul-li.

Actually i used:

```
.pagination > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also `centerPaginate` makes

`text-align:center;`

Please check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jmjm39x/) I tried.

thanks .

**UPDATE**  i used display:inline-flex, But it gives issues with IE 9 And Safari ,Any alternate solution ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use `display: inline-flex` rather than `inline-block`...

```
.pagination > li {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a `vertical-align: top;` to the `.nxt` class.

Comment: UPDATE i used display:inline-flex, But it gives issues with IE 9 And Safari ,Any alternate solution ? thanks.

Comment: vertical top Made my DAY :) Thanks

Comment: Did the `vertical-align` do it for you?

Comment: YES :) check this out . it works on ALL browsers .THANKS AGAIN . YOU will Experience/notice My thanks in Reality.http://jsfiddle.net/9jmjm39x/1/

Answer (score 1):

try following example. i just put structure for right arrow button same as left button. like `<li> <a>  abc </a> </li>`

```css
.pagination {
  /* display: inline-block;*/
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #282A2F;
}
.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  /*
  margin-left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  color:#fff;  text-align:center;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5fd3d2, #32d9b6); background: -o-linear-gradient(#5fd3d2, #32d9b6); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5fd3d2, #32d9b6);  background: linear-gradient(#5fd3d2, #32d9b6);
*/
}
.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.pagination > .disabled > span,
.pagination > .disabled > a,
.pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.pagination-lg > li > a,
.pagination-lg > li > span {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.pagination-sm > li > a,
.pagination-sm > li > span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
.pager {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.pager:before,
.pager:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.pager:after {
  clear: both;
}
.pager:before,
.pager:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.pager:after {
  clear: both;
}
.pager li {
  display: inline;
}
.pager li > a,
.pager li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.pager li > a:hover,
.pager li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.pager .next > a,
.pager .next > span {
  float: right;
}
.pager .previous > a,
.pager .previous > span {
  float: left;
}
.pager .disabled > a,
.pager .disabled > a:hover,
.pager .disabled > a:focus,
.pager .disabled > span {
  color: #999999;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/*new attr*/

li.prev,
li.next {
  float: none!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination centerPaginate">
  <li class="prev"><a href="/smudev/CourseCategories/index/reset:true" rel="prev"> &lt;&lt; </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/smudev/CourseCategories/index/reset:true">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled next"><a href="/smudev/CourseCategories/index/reset:true" rel="prev"> &gt;&gt; </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```