# How to center pagination without fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I have a pagination and want to center it:
http://jsfiddle.net/6819rhLf/

```
<ul class="slidesjs-pagination">
    <li class="slidesjs-pagination-item">
        <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="0" class="active">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slidesjs-pagination-item">
        <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="1">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slidesjs-pagination-item">
        <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="2">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`margin-left auto; margin-right: auto;` on `slidesjs-pagination` only works when `slidesjs-pagination` got a fixed width. But I can't tell how much items there will be, so fixed width will not do it for me.

The code is generated with JS, so I would like to have a solution where I don't need a parent div if that is possible.

Comment: Did you try setting the display of ul.slidesjs-pagination to "inline-block"?

Comment: possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width

Answer (score 1):

added a div around the ul,and added `cloud class` to CSS as below

```
<div class="cloud">
 //<ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

CSS class

```
.cloud
{
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6819rhLf/2/) please , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div with class container:

```
<div class="container">
```

then use CSS3:

```
div.container {
    height: 10em;
    position: relative }
div.container ul {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
```

This centers both horizontally and vertically, so you can play around to get the layout you want.

Comment: I hoped to find a solution without a parent div (cause the HTML comes from a plugin and does not have a container). I'm not sure if it's possible. If not I will add a container.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent `div` and set `ul` to `display:inline-block` and add `text-align:center` to parent

or if you already have a parent element then add `text-align:center` to it

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
.slidesjs-pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}
.slidesjs-pagination-item {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.slidesjs-pagination-item a {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/12x12");
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="slidesjs-pagination">
    <li class="slidesjs-pagination-item"> 
      <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="0" class="active">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slidesjs-pagination-item"> 
      <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="1">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slidesjs-pagination-item"> 
      <a href="#" data-slidesjs-item="2">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I hoped to find a solution without a parent div (cause the HTML comes from a plugin and does not have a container). I'm not sure if it's possible. If not I will add a container.

Comment: Without a parent container you could add the text-align:center property to the <body> tag (this still requires the <ul> to be display:inline-block).

Comment: it will make all the text align center

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{
  float:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 text-align:center;
}
ul li{
  float:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertically-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally benefit from the addition of an explanation.