# PhotoSwipe How to center vertically thumbnails? Thank

Tags: css, photoswipe

I have a problem, I don't understand why I can't get thumbnails center vertically on the list?

I tried:

```
.my-gallery figure {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 140px;}
```

and:

```
.my-gallery img {
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;}
```

...but the thumbnails are always aligned to top. 
My thumbnails do not have the same size and it is not very pretty.

Comment: your images shouldn't be any bigger than 1200x1200 or else they look fuuny

Comment: try a img{vertical-align:middle;}

Comment: here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g5y66dab/2/ (demo gallery of photoswipe)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdQgeY

Answer (score 2):

This actually helped me: [Centering a div block without the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width/6353345#6353345) .

Basically, create another div around the div that contains the gallery photos:

`<div id="container">
    <div id="gallery">
        <img></img>
    </div>
</div>`

Configure CSS:

`#gallery 
{
   display:inline-block;
}`

`#container 
{
    text-align: center;
}`