# Shrink anchor around centered block

Tags: html, css

How can I shrink an anchor (green border) around a centered image of arbitrary (not specified) width? In other words, I want the seconds box with the green border centered, just like the first one. No floats, no absolute positioning.

- Removing line (A) centers, but the anchor box remains elsewhere and cluttered.
- Changing line (A) to block makes the anchor full-width
- No luck with adding `margin: 0 auto` to the anchor either.

— No chance beyond a [(slightly dodgy) text-align center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284064/444255)?

[image]

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLMemK)

**html**

```
<img src="" width="123" height="100">  
<hr>
<a href='#'>  
    <img src="" width="123" height="100">  
</a>
```

**css**

```
img {
  display: block;
  background: #caa; /* red */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {    
  display: inline-block;  /* (A) */
  border: 4px solid #aca; /* green */
}
```

Comment: There is nothing “dogdy” about using `text-align` to align inline(-block) elements.

Comment: Agree with the above.  `text-align` is best if you want to keep the width of your anchor dependent on the content.  Otherwise you can set the width of your anchor explicitly and use `display:block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set against using absolute position, floats, specific width on the element, AND text-align: center (which is NOT dodgy in the least!), then your only other option is to fake a table.

```
img {
  display: block;
  background: #caa; /* red */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {    
  border: 4px solid #aca; /* green */
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I still don't understand why text-align: center is dodgy...

Comment: **That's a good solution!** ( text-align pushes things from block-resolving to inline-text-flow, whitespace starts to matter, etc... [also see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width/284064#284064) )

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping an image in another element merely transfers the centering requirement to the wrapper.

The image will now be centered in the wrapper (the anchor) due to the `margin:auto`...so you now have to center the wrapper.

BUT you want that wrapper to shrink-to-fit around the image. There are only a few ways on doing that AND centering the result.

Using `text-align:center` despite the link you mentioned which is seven years old is the optimal and most supported option.

I think you will find that support for text-align isn't even close to spotty any more.

If you want another non-float, non-positioned answer then it will be the less well supported flexbox option.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  display: block;
  background: #caa;
  /* red */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
  border: 4px solid #aca;
  /* green */
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-123-100-3.jpg">
</a>
```