# How to center a component without knowing its width in Css

Tags: html, css

How to center a component without knowing its width value. I know that you can position a component in the center by writing this in css:

```
Width: componentWidth; 
margin: auto;
```

But in my case it's a generic style (given to different kind of buttons with different with value).

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: complete `HTML` and `CSS` please

Comment: Check this other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` on your container.

For example

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="content">Center!</span>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="container2">
  <span class="content2">Center 2!</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

.container2 {
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7so2tqnx/)

The second container is an example of how to vertically center something, as an added bonus.

Answer (score 2):

`margin: auto;` will work when you have some fixed width defined to your element, if you have *dynamic* width, you can use `transform: translateX(-50%);` to center your element horizontally(which I assume is what you want) or you can add `translateY(-50%)` if you want to center vertically.

For example:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  /* specifying x and y separately on purpose so that you understand whats going 
     on and what you can remove what you don't need from the above snippet */
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3o0uvxxk/)

If you want just horizontal centered element, get rid of `top: 50%` and `translateY(-50%)` respectively. Just note that it's a good practice to nest your `absolute` positioned element inside `relative` positioned element.

Comment: That works, but not for all browsers (Safari for instance)

Comment: This is the correct answer. To make safari compatible, use `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Answer (score 1):

In order for `margin: auto` to work, you must also have `block` as the display type. The display type for links and buttons is `inline-block` by default, so override this with `display: block;` in your style:

```
.whatever-your-btn-class-is {
  margin: auto;
  width: componentWidth;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without CSS or knowing an elements size using a table if you want to get old school.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center"><!-- anything in here will be centered --></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's an example

https://jsfiddle.net/gxyyecdy/