# Centering a div with dynamic width, containing cards

Tags: html, css

How can I centre the following element:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="cards card1">Card 1</div>
    <div class="cards card2">Card 2</div>
    <div class="cards card3">Card 3</div>
    <div class="cards card4">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The number of cards is dynamically set. So is the width of outer div. Depending on the width of outer div, I would like to display them like this:

```
|                                    |
|    |Card 1 | |Card 2 | |Card 3|    |
|    |       | |       | |      |    |
|                                    |
|    |Card 4 |                       |
|    |       |                       |



|                           |
|    |Card 1 | |Card 2 |    |
|    |       | |       |    |
|                           |
|    |Card 3 | |Card 4 |    |
|    |       | |       |    |



|                                              |
|    |Card 1 | |Card 2 | |Card 3| |Card 4 |    |
|    |       | |       | |      | |       |    |
```

There are other questions like this ([Centering a div block without the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283961/centering-a-div-block-without-the-width)), however they don't deal with multiple rows of cards.
I have tried using the following:

```
.outer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

However this puts Card 4 is in the middle not on the left.

Or

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%); 
  left: 50%;
}
```

This works, but only when there is a single row of cards. When there are more cards than fit in one row, it aligns everything left.

Answer (score 2):

Does this address what you're trying to do?

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cards {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="cards card1">Card 1</div>
    <div class="cards card2">Card 2</div>
    <div class="cards card3">Card 3</div>
    <div class="cards card4">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, in case when outer div is wide enough, I would like all of the cards to be in one row. In case when it's too short for three cards, then it should have two rows of two.

Comment: @Honey_Badger It feels like you're looking for a pure `CSS` solution. If so, I don't see how this will work, as it appears you would need container queries (not yet a thing) for this to work. Is `JavaScript` a no-no for this?

Comment: I would prefer CSS only if possible. I guess alternative is to set width of `.inner` on `window.onresize`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cards {
    width: calc(33.3333% - 40px);
    height: 270px;
    background-color: bisque;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="cards card1">Card 1</div>
    <div class="cards card2">Card 2</div>
    <div class="cards card3">Card 3</div>
    <div class="cards card4">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards {
    width: calc(33.3333% - 40px);
    height: 270px;
    background-color: bisque;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="cards card1">Card 1</div>
    <div class="cards card2">Card 2</div>
    <div class="cards card3">Card 3</div>
    <div class="cards card4">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cards {
    width: 200px;
    height: 270px;
    background-color: bisque;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="cards">Card 1</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 2</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 3</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 4</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 5</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 6</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 7</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 8</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 9</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 10</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 11</div>
    <div class="cards">Card 12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello from Russia! I love people from USA, Europe, Asia. So you want to do?

Comment: Thank you, I would like the cards to align depending on the width of the outer div. This will not always leave space for three cards, the number will depend on the width.

Comment: @Honey_Badger In this case, you need to specify a fixed width of the cards. I made three examples for you. What you want is the last, third example. I do not perfectly know English. But, I can do any designs, structure, construction. Contact us.

Comment: Yes, the width of the cards is set. The third example is correctly aligning the cards, however, as you can see, the `.inner` element is not centred but aligned left. I am trying to have equal margins on left and right.

Comment: @Honey_Badger Good. I can build what you want. But for this I need more data:
1) Minimum site width
2) Maximum website width
3) Card width
4) All margin from one card to another
Unit pixels

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flex: auto` on your cards.

```
.cards { 
   flex: auto; 
}
```

This is the same as `flex: 1 1 auto`, which in turn is short-hand for `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: auto`;

Then on `.inner` use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`

```
.inner { 
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

---

Have a look at the **css** in this snippet. It has a little playground so you can adjust the `.outer` container width dynamically, as well as the outer padding, card margins, and card paddings:

If you prefer, you can try the [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/qvYWRx?editors=1100):

```js
var controlContainer=document.createElement("div");controlContainer.innerHTML='<div style="margin: 0px 0px 20px; display: flex; width: 100%; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-around;" class="controls"><div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 30px;"><input class="outer-ctrl" type="range" min="100" max="1200" value="300"><label> <code>.outer { width: <span class="outer-span">300px</span> } </code></label></div><div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 30px;"><input class="outer-padding" type="range" min="0" max="30" value="0"><label><code>.outer: { padding: <span class="padding-span">0px</span> }</code></label></div><div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 30px;"><input class="card-margin" type="range" min="0" max="30" value="0"><label><code>.cards { margin: <span class="margin-span">0px</span> }</code></label></div><div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 30px;"><input class="card-padding" type="range" min="0" max="30" value="0"><label><code>.cards { padding: <span class="card-padding-span">0px</span> }</code></label></div></div>',document.body.prepend(controlContainer),document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function(e){e.style.cssText="background: black;color:white;padding: 7px;"}),document.querySelectorAll(".cards").forEach(function(e){e.style.cssText="background:yellow; border: 1px solid blue;"}),document.querySelector(".outer-ctrl").addEventListener("input",function(e){var n="".concat(e.target.value,"px");document.querySelector(".outer").style.width=n,document.querySelector(".outer-span").innerText=n}),document.querySelector(".card-margin").addEventListener("input",function(e){var n="".concat(e.target.value,"px");document.querySelectorAll(".cards").forEach(function(e){e.style.margin=n}),document.querySelector(".margin-span").innerText=n}),document.querySelector(".outer-padding").addEventListener("input",function(e){var n="".concat(e.target.value,"px");document.querySelector(".outer").style.padding=n,document.querySelector(".padding-span").innerText=n}),document.querySelectorAll(".cards").forEach(function(e){e.style.cssText="background:yellow; border: 1px solid blue;"}),document.querySelector(".card-padding").addEventListener("input",function(e){var n="".concat(e.target.value,"px");document.querySelectorAll(".cards").forEach(function(e){e.style.padding=n}),document.querySelector(".card-padding-span").innerText=n}),document.body.style.cssText="margin:0;padding:0;",document.querySelector(".outer").style.border="1px solid #333;";
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cards {
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="cards card1">Card 1</div>
    <div class="cards card2">Card 2</div>
    <div class="cards card3">Card 3</div>
    <div class="cards card4">Card 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close to what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a way to make the card width set, say 100px?